# Почему так прыгают блоки

Tags: jquery

Разрабатываю dashboard для заказчика и тут такой нюанс - при просмотре страницы нижние блоки некорректно отображаются, но если изменить размер окна браузера, они встают нормально. Вот сам код работы и название плагина соответственно. `.inner_rb_wrapper` - класс оболочки, к которой применяется JS-скрипт(для внутренних блоков)

```
<script src="/template/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/template/js/plugins/jquery.freetile.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).on('load resize', function() {

    if ($(window).width() > 425) {

        $('.inner_rb_wrapper').freetile({
            animate: true,
            elementDelay: 30
        });

    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Ссылка на сайт как бы моветон здесь, к тому же никакой проблемы на сайте я не вижу(Ubuntu Chrome). Локализуйте проблему и предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: решение проблемы, связанной с конкретным плагином я рекомендую смотреть в ишьюс этого плагина, например тут: https://github.com/yconst/Freetile/issues/10 автор говорит, что _freetile does not work well with % layouts. I intend on trying to fix that at some point._